# How did they get this answer for All strings that do not have the substring 'ab'?

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions and I trying to learn it and I came across this question

Regular expressions -- `Let the alphabet = {a,b}.`   Write regular expressions for:

```
All strings that do not have the substring 'ab'
```

How did they get the answer `b*a*`?   I thought with the Kleene star between b and a here you could have ab, also does the order matter?

I found it here: http://courses.washington.edu/css448/zander/Notes/reg343ans.txt.

Comment: If that's the only part of the regex, it should match literally anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regexes the order does matter.

```
b*a*
```

means 0 or more 'b's followed by 0 or more 'a's. (This is assuming that the regex search anchors to the start and end of the string - in most regex syntaxes this would actually be written as: ^b*a*$)

So, it would match

- any number of 'a's
- any number of 'b's
- any number of 'b's followed by any number of 'a's

It's a strange question, but they are right. If you only have a and b as possible characters, then any sequence with b following a with have the substring 'ab'

Comment: The key is that a can be repeated 0 times and so can b.  Therefore, these have absolutely no effect because the regex has nothing that it needs to look for, literally.

Comment: I've added a note that this assumes the regex is anchored. Depending on the actual type/usage of the regex this may or may not be the case

Comment: thx...that explains it....gotta practice more of these types of problems...since I'm just newbie to this stuff,they are just hard to understand